# Jenkins + Sonarqube Android bytecode analysis

Tags: java, android, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to analyze bytecode of Android application with SonarQube.
SonarQube analysis is invoked by gradle task     `:sonarqube`

According to sonarQube documentation:
1)http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle
gradle plugin `"org.sonarqube"` should be used

2)http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode
in project settings should be set parameters like:`sonar.java.libraries` and `sonar.java.binaries`.

This is my gradle configuration

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
    dependencies {
        //other
        classpath "org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.0"
    }
}

sonarqube  {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "username"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "password"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "ProjectKey"
        property "sonar.projectName", "ProjectName"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1"
        property "sonar.sources", "src"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "C:/Jenkins/jobs/ProjectName/workspace/build/intermediates/classes/"
        property "sonar.java.libraries", "C:/Jenkins/jobs/ProjectName/workspace/lib/*.jar"
    }
}
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    into "lib"
    from configurations.compile
}
```

In `C:/Jenkins/jobs/ProjectName/workspace/build/intermediates/classes/` I put all *.class files that are produced during compilation of Android application.

In `C:/Jenkins/jobs/ProjectName/workspace/lib/`i put all *.jar libraries that are produced by task `copyRuntimeLibs`.

Sonarqube analysis invoked by gradle task in Jenkins:

I get an error for every class in my application:

```
Class 'EveryClassInApplication' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

What do I miss?

Comment: You should not have to set manually sonar.java.libraries or sonar.java.binaries manually when using gradle or maven. What do you mean exactly when you say : "I want to analyze bytecode ", do you mean you want to provide bytecode to the analyzer ?

Comment: I tried as well without
sonar.java.libraries
sonar.java.binaries

I mean that design metrics in sonarQube require bytecode to compute certain metrics (like dependency matrix).
I want to provide *.class files to sonarQube